# Deploy Azure Table via Azure Resource Manager Template

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-resource-manager

So now that it's (apparently) possible to create Blob Containers via an ARM template, is it possible to similarly create an Azure Storage Table?  I've searched around but most of the answers are from before Blob Container creation was implemented and available.

I've also found the documentation for the REST API at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-table but I'm not sure if and how this maps to the JSON entry in an ARM template.

I'm looking to eliminate the PowerShell script that currently handles the creation of the Table resources in my deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to update this with an answer for anyone in the future trying to setup an ARM template with table service as the current documentation seems very vague in how these should be implemented. Specifically note the format of the names and that all items are defined as root level resources:

```
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccount_name'),'/', parameters('tableServiceName'))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices",
    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
    "properties": {
        "cors": {
            "corsRules": [
                {
                    "allowedOrigins": [
                        "*"
                    ],
                    "allowedMethods": [
                        "PUT",
                        "GET",
                        "POST"
                    ],
                    "maxAgeInSeconds": 0,
                    "exposedHeaders": [
                        "*"
                    ],
                    "allowedHeaders": [
                        "*"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccount_name'))]"
    ],
    "resources": []
},
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccount_name'),'/default/',parameters('table_name'))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables",
    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices', parameters('storageAccount_name'), 'default')]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccount_name'))]"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of the 2019-06-01 version ... **Yes**

<s>No, this is not currently possible to do with an ARM template.</s>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/table/create
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2019-06-01/storageaccounts/tableservices

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices",
  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "cors": {
      "corsRules": [
        {
          "allowedOrigins": [
            "string"
          ],
          "allowedMethods": [
            "string"
          ],
          "maxAgeInSeconds": "integer",
          "exposedHeaders": [
            "string"
          ],
          "allowedHeaders": [
            "string"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and tables:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables",
  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01"
}
```

Comment: i think it is, check this api

Comment: @llazar response indicates it is now possible using ARM templates. Can that response be made the answer, as answer is no longer correct

Comment: hope you understand I have thousands of answers on stack overflow, I cant be following all of them and editing. Just edit my answer to make it right. @SteveC

Comment: Totally understand, and wasn't meant to be pushy ... I was interested in if there was a process to change an approved answer, when it became invalid, over to a correct one.

Comment: i dont think there is one, but you can always edit existing answer

Answer (score 3):

From 2019-06-01 is possible to create Table Services and Tables.

Table Services

```
   {
  "name": "default",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices",
  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
  "properties": {
    "cors": {
      "corsRules": [
        {
          "allowedOrigins": [
            "string"
          ],
          "allowedMethods": [
            "string"
          ],
          "maxAgeInSeconds": "integer",
          "exposedHeaders": [
            "string"
          ],
          "allowedHeaders": [
            "string"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "resources": []
}
```

Tables

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables",
  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01"
  }
```

See the references [Azure Storage Account Table Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2019-06-01/storageaccounts/tableservices)

Answer (score 3):

Sample ARM Template to create Blob and Table in a storage account

```js
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Specifies the name of the Azure Storage account."
        }
      },
      "containerName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "logs",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Specifies the name of the blob container."
        }
      },
      "tableName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "logstable",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Specifies the name of the table."
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Specifies the location in which the Azure Storage resources should be deployed."
        }
      }
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard_GRS",
          "tier": "Standard"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "properties": {
          "accessTier": "Hot",
          "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
          "allowBlobPublicAccess": false,
          "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
        },
        "resources": [
          {
            "type": "blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat('default/', parameters('containerName'))]",
            "dependsOn": [
              "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "tableServices/tables",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "[concat('default/', parameters('tableName'))]",
            "dependsOn": [
              "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
            ]
          }
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now only container is available. Microsoft are working on tables.

Comment: yes only containers for now, https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-storage-blob-container/azuredeploy.json

Comment: @arishshetty Wow! Seems a bit of an omission. Is it possible now, i.e. about 2 years later?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CreateIfNotExistsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.createifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet) method in your code

[image]
In case your azure storage table does not yet exist it will create it. So you don't have to add things in the ARM templates.